# Get hash of commit with latest tag on current branch

Tags: git

I need to get the hash of the latest tag commit on the current branch.

If I do

```
git show-ref --tag
```

I do get all tags and their commit ids, but I just need the latest one and only the hash itself.

Doing

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

Only gives me the latest tag, but no hash...

So I did

```
git tag --list --format '%(refname:short) %(objectname:short)'
```

But still it is a complete list and I only need the last id.

Comment: Can you use other command line tools? Such as grep, sed, etc?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes I can, as far it is running at busybox

Comment: If `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` gives you the latest tag, can't you just pass that value to `git rev-parse` to get the commit id?

Comment: `git describe  --always --long`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk This would give me the latest commit at all, not the commit with the last tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | xargs git rev-parse
```

Comment: What is the difference to `git rev-parse $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)`

Comment: Output wise, no difference.